# Get the name under which a variable or property is stored

Tags: python

Is there a way to get the name under which a variable or a property is stored?

Something like:

```
class X:
  def __init__(self):
    self.name = __name_under_which_I_m_stored__

jeff = X()
print(jeff.name) # yields 'jeff'
```

Pretty sure that this is not possible, but you never know... Furthermore, I'm aware that the name could be unspecified (`do_something(X())`) or ambiguous (`jeff=frank=X()`).

Comment: Do you mean to get the property based on value. For example if self.x = 5, you want to get `x` when `5` is passed? else, provide some example.

Answer (score 3):

The Python VM has no way to know the literal name of a name. For objects, you can access the name via `__name__` attribute.

If you want to do this, you'll need to implement a mapping of names to values. You can do this with a `dict`.

```
class X:
  def __init__(self):
    self.names = {};

  def set(self, name, value):
    self.names[name] = value

  def get(self, name):
      return (name, self.names[value])



jeff = X()
jeff.set("name", "jeff");
print(jeff.get("name")) # yields ("name", "jeff")
```